# How can I limit the result to a field with array that has a specific value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to display a single article only with those comments (it is an array) which have the approve value set to "true" in my database. I can't get the correct result. Here is my backend code. I use pure MongoDB, without Mongoose.

```
        app.get("/posts/:id", function (req,res) {
        blog.collection("posts").findOne({"_id":ObjectId(req.params.id)}
            ,function (error,post )
        {
            res.render("user/post",{post:post});
        });
    });
```

Here is what my database looks like, I want to filter or limit the result to comment approve = "true".

[image: The appearance of my database]

Thank you very much for every answer.

Comment: Is it a requirement to filter out the approved comments from the backend or it's okay for the filtering to be done in the front end?

Comment: I did it on the front-end side. Thank you for your willingness to help.

Comment: Please don't past images, use formatted text instead.

Comment: Ok, I will be remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is better solution but it can be obtained by this:

```
let newPost = {...post}
newPost.comments = newPost.comments.filter(comment=>comment.approve)
res.render("user/post",{post:newPost});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved front-end display with if (comment.approve == "true")